# Error when saving geodataframe to geojson after a spatial join

Tags: geojson, geopandas

I am writing a simple python code to perform sjoin on two geodataframe.

```
    gdf1 = gpd.read_file(polygon1.geojson)
    gdf2 = gpd.read_file(polygon2.geojson)
    gdf = gpd.sjoin(gdf1, gdf2, how="left", op='intersects')
    gdf.to_file(filename= 'myfile.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

However, I encounter this error when writing the result to geojson.

I can avoid this error by writing to a shapefile then convert the shapefile to geojson. But this sounds too odd.

Is there anyone know the root cause of such an error?

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py
> in to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, index, **kwargs)
> 531         from geopandas.io.file import to_file
> 532
> --> 533         to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, index, **kwargs)
> 534
> 535     def to_crs(self, crs=None, epsg=None, inplace=False):
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in
> to_file(df, filename, driver, schema, index, **kwargs)
> 191             filename, "w", driver=driver, crs_wkt=crs_wkt, schema=schema, **kwargs
> 192         ) as colxn:
> --> 193             colxn.writerecords(df.iterfeatures())
> 194
> 195
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py in
> writerecords(self, records)
> 347         if self.mode not in ('a', 'w'):
> 348             raise IOError("collection not open for writing")
> --> 349         self.session.writerecs(records, self)
> 350         self._len = self.session.get_length()
> 351         self._bounds = self.session.get_extent()
>
> fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.writerecs()
>
> fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.OGRFeatureBuilder.build()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error was caused by duplicated column name.

There were two columns in my dataset having the same name and the geopandas seemed to be not case sensitive.

After renaming one of the columns, I can write to geojson without any issue~

Comment: You can accept your own answer with the checkbox